# Rewrite url path to new path using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

in my htaccess file, i have this, that is supposed to remove the `index.php?` from the path and make the path look like this: `video/:AccountId/:recordId` however something isnt working correctly. it doesnt re-write anymore and i can only make the url work by having the index.php? tag in it, so instead it looks like: `video/index.php?/:AccountId/:recordId`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
  #  slashes.
  # If your page resides at
  #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
  # then use
  # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
  RewriteBase /video
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I cant just remove it because the clients already have the `video/:AccountId/:recordId` i dont want to have to email blast them to change something on their end to make this work, i was hoping too that maybe someone would know how to redirect that url to the one that includes the index.php? because overall i dont care that its there or not, its a hold over from previous teams.

Comment: Could you please do mention what sample url you are hitting?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, i believe what you are asking is what is the full URL that my clients are hitting, and that would be `{serverLocation}/video/:AccountID/:recordId` i either need to find out why my htacess file isnt redirecting like its supposed to, or redirect the clients to `{serverlocation}/video/index.php?/:AccountID/:recordID`

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess rules file. Make sure your htaccess file is present along with video OR first level of URL folder, also make sure index.php is present inside that folder eg: `.htaccess and video are existing together AND index.php is inside video folder).

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(.*)/?$ /$1/index.php?/$2/$3 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesnt work, if you go to `https://embed.truthcasting.com/video/100003752/209435` it doesnt redirect from `video/{Number}/{Number}` to `video/index.php?/{Number}/{Number}`

Comment: @AustinHoward, I believe you should put `&` inspite of `/` after index.php. if yes then change last line to `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(.*)/?$ /$1/index.php?$2&$3 [QSA,L]` and try once

Comment: Ok, so i, in part know a little more about whats going on, im getting a 404 on the https://embed.truthcasting.com/video/100003752/209435 it cant redirect, cause its expecting a page that doesnt exist.

Comment: @AustinHoward, could you please make sure that your folder/files are in following manner `/root/video/index.php` and`/root/.htaccess` and `/root/video` you can change root to any other your folder path name it's just an example. Let me know if we are having same config here?

Comment: unfortunately this did not work. however we were able to find a solution that works for now, regardless that didnt involve the .htaccess file. however i appreciate your comments.